# iterate through and map a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to apply a function to each of the values at all levels of the array:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[[1,2],[1,2]],1,2,3]
```

for example, multiply all the values by 3, and map it in the same format as before so I get:

```
arr = [[3,6,9],[3,6,9],[[3,6],[3,6]],3,6,9]
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Recursion seems to be your best bet.

Comment: thanks, any ideas on how I would go about that ?

Comment: See my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion. Create a method that will call itself if the element is array, do your calculation if it is not.

```rb
def walk_array(array)
  array.map do |element|
    if element.is_a?(Array)
      walk_array(element)
    else
      element * 3
    end
  end
end

arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[[1,2],[1,2]],1,2,3] 
# => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [[1, 2], [1, 2]], 1, 2, 3]

walk_array(arr) 
# => [[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [[3, 6], [3, 6]], 3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a gem, I wrote a module that provides exactly this functionality: https://github.com/dgopstein/deep_enumerable

```
>> require 'deep_enumerable'
>> arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[[1,2],[1,2]],1,2,3]

>> arr.deep_map_values{|x| x*3}
=> [[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [[3, 6], [3, 6]], 3, 6, 9]
```